# snakemake "one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!"

Tags: bash, snakemake, drop, rna-seq

Hi I am trying to run a pipeline using snakemake. Specifically, I am running a demo rna-seq analysis pipeline after following the instructions specified here: https://gagneurlab-drop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

when I run `snakemake --cores 1` i get the following error message::

```
    Error in rule aberrantExpression_bamStats:
    jobid: 26
    output: /Users/00104561/drop_demo/Output/processed_data/aberrant_expression/v29/coverage/HG00126.1.M_111124_8.tsv
    shell:
        
        # identify chromosome format
        if samtools idxstats /Users/00104561/drop_demo/Data/rna_bam/HG00126.1.M_111124_8_chr21.bam | grep -qP "^chr";
        then
            chrNames=$(cut -f1 Scripts/AberrantExpression/pipeline/resource/chr_UCSC_NCBI.txt | tr '
' '|')
        else
            chrNames=$(cut -f2 Scripts/AberrantExpression/pipeline/resource/chr_UCSC_NCBI.txt | tr '
' '|')
        fi

        # write coverage from idxstats into file
        count=$(samtools idxstats /Users/00104561/drop_demo/Data/rna_bam/HG00126.1.M_111124_8_chr21.bam | grep -E "^($chrNames)" |                 cut -f3 | paste -sd+ - | bc)

        echo -e "HG00126.1.M_111124_8   ${count}" > /Users/00104561/drop_demo/Output/processed_data/aberrant_expression/v29/coverage/HG00126.1.M_111124_8.tsv
        
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

any help would be appreciated! i am very new to bioinformatics!

Comment: "Strict mode" doesn't really exist, but it's what some tools call turning on a series of options that instruct the shell to fail if any commands do. (Unfortunately, some of those options have unwanted side effects and are a bad idea to use in general -- see the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) demonstrating in particular how `set -e` makes some of the shell's behavior extremely surprising to readers, and also reduces portability across version boundaries).

Comment: For example, if the snakemake idea of "strict mode" contains both `pipefail` and `errexit`, then any `grep` you include somewhere in a pipeline will cause the whole command to be considered a failure if there aren't even matches -- even if you consider emitting an empty string as output a perfectly acceptable outcome.

Comment: Anyhow, I'd suggest putting `set -x` inside the shell script and then reading the trace logged to stderr to see exactly where it stops.

Comment: Looks like you are using a bash script from the `shell` section. Snakemake doesn't support bash: you need to extract the script into a .sh file and run it from `shell`.

Answer (score 3):

The message "one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code" indicates that the shell command was successfully launched, but it reported an error (non zero exit code).

So something went wrong with the command you asked snakemake to run. Try running the reported command directly from the command line without snakemake, it may be easier to debug that way.

This recent answer to a similar question explained it well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176454/663466

Comment: This is good guidance, but I'm not sure it actually constitutes an answer. Questions that aren't answerable (f/e, because they don't have a [mre]) should be commented on and potentially closed (until edited to be improved), as opposed to given half-answers whose applicability/utility can't be guaranteed.